# What file manipulation commands work across all operating systems?

Tags: python, file-manager, file-manipulation

I'm making a python script that will perform various file manipulation functions. I need it to work across all operating systems so the commands I use can't be specific to any one operating system. I can't used any os commands, and can't use any system() calls. Is there any replacement for the following commands?

os.mknod() - create a file

os.remove() - delete a file

os.rename() - rename a file

os.listdir() - list directory

In addition, does shutil work across all operating systems? I have a function to move a file from one directory to another using shutil.move() but unsure if this can work on OSX and Windows (I have a linux computer). I looked at the shutil documentation but it doesn't mention anything about working on any operating system.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to list those _all operating systems_.

Comment: "I can't used any os commands" - you're going to have to explain why you have that restriction, because that's a lot like asking how to walk if you're not allowed to use legs.

Comment: It's for a project at school. The prof indicated the following : Design a portable file manipulator, called pofm, which will operate on files. pofm must have the following attributes:

- You can write it in any programming language of your choice.

-Since it must be portable, it must NOT use any OS commands which means that pofm can be easily ported to any operating system and platform. For example, if you use C programming, all commands must be standard C functions, and you cannot use the system() calls.

Comment: "it must NOT use any OS commands" is most likely not referring to the `os` module. Most likely, it is referring to OS-specific APIs.

Comment: @user2357112 okay so i'm currently using the os module for os.mknod(), os.remove(), os.rename(), os.listdir()

What can I use instead?

Comment: I'm saying that those functions are probably *what you're supposed to use*.

Comment: the `os` module functions should work on all python-supported systems, unless claimed otherwise

Comment: @user2357112 Okay great Thanks!